# GCM push not working with parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging

I am using self hosted parse server version `2.2.19`. I have already setup the push certificates for ios(APNS) and works fine. Now doing the same as before to GCM. But the GCM doesn't work. The senderIDs, keys are all correct, the device is hits the parse server and installs too, but the push is not working.

With the recent Firebase/FCM available, is GCM service stopped for new projects? I have old projects using GCM which work perfectly fine on the self hosted parse server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recent FCM changes made it so you cannot specify your type of key in GCM anymore, so you can't specifically grab your server key.

Instead you need to grab your server key from FCM and use that from now on.

First, head over to the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com). If your project is already in firebase, simply enter that project. Otherwise, click `CREATE NEW PROJECT`. Then navigate to your project's settings:

[image]

From here, switch to the Cloud Messaging tab. You will see two keys. The first, your server key, and the second, your Sender ID.

[image]

Use these keys now instead of the ones generated in GCM.

Note that your old setup WILL still work. But if you want to do things going forward, you need to use these instead.

Also note that on the Android side you *do not* need to update to Firebase. You can still use your old system.

Comment: if thats so its great... I can't try this out right now but will do asap and get to you.